# Flagged post neither helpful nor declined or disputed

Tags: discussion, flags

I flagged [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15030231/is-love-2d-a-good-programming-language-to-make-a-top-down-shooter) as low quality. On my flagging history page, the flag is not marked as one of the usual (`helpful` / `declined` / `disputed`). Instead it is showing **none**. Also there is a post script message on the bottom of the flag list, which says:

> older flags were not recorded helpful/declined

What does **none** mean? Why is the message being shown on the flag history page?

Comment: @gnat.. Thanks for pointing out. The duplicate didn't show up in the suggestions while typing the question.